# ¿Como se renombran los packages en Android Studio de una forma sencilla?

Tags: android-studio

¿Como se hace para renombrar los paquetes java en Android Studio? Con eclipse era un procedimiento muy sencillo, y suficiente con una opción `refactor` en el menú.

Pero con el Android Studio con la opcion `Refactor` > `Rename` me abre una ventana que indica que hay multiples directorios asociados al paquete, y pregunta si quiero renombrar el paquete o el directorio.... y los resultados no son los esperados.

¿Cual sería la forma mas sencilla para renombrar un paquete con el Android Studio?

Comment: Ponle rename y te preguntara que clases ocupan ese package para remplazarles por el nuevo nombre.

Answer (score 1):

Pablo, la forma adecuada es precisamente como lo indicas, refactorizando, anteriormente Eclipse no te indicaba nada y todo era cambiado de nombre. Con Android Studio te avisa para evitar algún posible problema lo cual agrega más control a los cambios.

En realidad cambiar el "paquete" definido en las clases, implica que también se cambiaría el nombre del directorio.

Manualmente cambiar los paquetes no creo que sea la solución para un desarrollador, ya que al cambiar el nombre del paquete (folder) tienes que cambiar las referencias en las clases.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla es ubicarte en el directorio del proyecto usando tu explorador de archivos ya sea de Windows o Linux. Entras a tu proyecto y vas cambiando el nombre de las carpetas de una a una, ejemplo:

com>tupackage>tuApp

Bueno pienso que eso mas sencillo para mí.

Comment: de hecho, creo que eso es lo más complicado y engorroso, porque que ocurre si son 80 package? He visto proyectos que los tienen